# Restlet with many @Get in my server side

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, objectify

So I am new with restlet. I am creating a Android application that can communicate with a GAE server (with objectify DB)
I Did this very good tutorial to learn:
http://www.tutos-android.com/webservice-rest-android-appengine-restlet-objectify

It's working very well but do very little.
Onely 2 methods:

```
public interface UserControllerInterface {
@Put
void create(User user);
@Get
Container getAllUsers();
}
```

For my application its more complicated so I add many more methods:

```
public interface UserControllerInterface {
@Put
public void createUser(ObagooUser user);

@Put
public void createMessage(ObagooUser user, String message);

@Put
public void updateMessage(ObagooMessage message);

@Get
public List<ObagooUser> getAllUser();

@Get
public ObagooUser getUserById(String id);

@Get
public List<ObagooMessage> getAllMessage();

@Get
public List<ObagooMessage> getAllMessageFromSender(ObagooUser sender);

@Get
public ObagooMessage getFreeMessage(ObagooUser user);
}
```

Each of these mothds working server side (I tested with Junit).

Now I am coding the android part and I am having problems.
When I do a simple call to getAllMessage() I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.createKey(KeyFactory.java:44)
at     com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.typedKeyToRawKey(ObjectifyFactory.java:269)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl.find(ObjectifyImpl.java:159)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl.find(ObjectifyImpl.java:183)
at com.obagoo.dao.ObagooUserDAO.getUserById(ObagooUserDAO.java:43)
at com.obagoo.controller.ObagooController.getUserById(ObagooController.java:47)
```

It's going in the wrong method (getUserById).

I put a break point in my getAllMessage and it's going in, but it is also going in other methods.

If I test many times, sometimes it's calling, createUser or another random method.

Do you see what I am doind wrong?

Adding the getAllMessage code:

```
public List<ObagooMessage> getAllMessage() {
    // logger.debug("Getting all Obagoo Messages");

    List<ObagooMessage> msg = new ArrayList<ObagooMessage>();
    Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();

    Query<ObagooMessage> q = ofy.query(ObagooMessage.class);

    for (ObagooMessage u : q) {
        msg.add(u);
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your router? http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/tutorial#part11

Comment: So what url would you use for each of the different methods? What url would you use to `getAllUser` (which by the way should be plural.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples that I've seen, its always shown that you should separate the `controller`/`resource` handling the `URI` for the list resource from the single item (`id`/`name` based) resource.  So you would have something like:

```
router.attach("/users", UsersController.class);
router.attach("/users/{id}", UserController.class
router.attach("/messages", MessagesController.class);
```

Notice the plural naming on the first class: `UsersController`, and singular naming on the the second class: `UserController`.  The first class would handle cases where no id was being provided, such as a get of all users. Also, note when the id is provided in the `URI`, it can be automatically mapped into an id field on the class. So the `Get` method has no parameters on the method call.

As for handling a subset, then for messages from a specific user, that could be handled with query parameters.  For instance when calling via a `URI` with `/messages?sender=id`, the `MessagesController.class` would use the following in the method handling the Get:

```
Form queryParams = getRequest().getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm(); 
String id = queryParams.getFirstValue("sender");
```

Hope that helps.  I'm no expert, so anyone feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

As error says: you are creating a key with zero Id.

My gues is that your `ObagoMessage` Id field is `long`? You should make it `Long`. Primitive `long` Id values are not autogenerated, while object type `Long` are. See the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Create_Your_Entity_Classes).

Comment: I don't want to use long for my id, but the question is, why does it want to create a message when I call getAllMessage()?? I could put a long as id, but I think there is something I don't understand... In my getAllMessage() the code is very simple, it's juste a find. There is no creation. Why the code is going into method I never call??

Comment: Yes, I had it in the question

Comment: I made more tests: I put a log in each method and comment all other code. It's not calling the right method. I wonder if it's possible with restlet to have many method with @Get in the same controller class....

Comment: Also I find this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/7608694/… I really wonder if restlet is useful if I have to put the name of the  method in the URI and if I need to have one controller class for each get method... I am used to spring, and it's quite disturbing... or maybe I misunderstand something...

Comment: Clearly it is more a question about proper web API design (REST). You should try to define more resources than you currently do, so you won't need several GET/PUT methods for the same resource which is generally a sign that something goes wrong.

Comment: In some cases, you can need to have several @Get for the same resource, but in this case you need to use query parameters and define them like this: @Get("?param={paramValue}" or just @Get("?param")

Comment: Thanks Jerome. Now I am wondering why is it useful to use restlet... If I have to create one controller for each @Get, then I don't see the point. This make multiply the number of classes... I am not used to this with Spring/J2EE, maybe there is something I don't understand.... Any way thanks for your answer, I ll do it that way and see where it goes ;)

Comment: If find this link which explain well what is restful framework: http://adityakeyal.blogspot.fr/2011/03/what-are-rest-soap-json_04.html